# Ubuntu stuck when load with connected external monitor

Tags: 16.04, hdmi, xps

I have Dell XPS 15, and when I load the system with connected external monitor by HDMI, the system gets stuck on the login screen.

I use Nvidia-361 driver with Bumblebee.

The laptop has a 4k screen but external monitor has only full-HD resolution.

Comment: Is it only stuck with the second monitor connected or does the problem persist even if you leave the monitor disconnected?

Comment: @Videonauth persist only with connected second monitor. If i connect monitor after load (I use i3wm) then load fine. But sometimes it stuck after configure some parameters by xrandr to adjust some settings.